# Calculate time between login and logout for repeated access per day

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table which has Employee_id, time and type.

Description of Row:

```
Employee_id - Provides ID of an employee
Time - Date and Time when the event occurs for a particular event we have id in Type.
Type - Login, Logout.
```

I have to calculate how long they are in their account one time they login and logout? if they login and logout 2 times a day, so the result should show 2 rows with the time they spent each time? if they have 2 login before a logout choose the highest one

```
Employee_id     time                    type
504             04/03/2015 1:05:02 PM   Login
504             04/03/2015 3:26:16 PM   logout
504             04/03/2015 3:28:52 PM   Login
504             04/03/2015 3:29:04 PM   Login
504             04/03/2015 3:30:25 PM   logout
504             04/03/2015 3:31:41 PM   Login
504             04/03/2015 5:40:19 PM   logout
505             04/03/2015 5:43:40 PM   Login
505             04/03/2015 8:17:59 PM  logout
505             04/03/2015 10:07:59 PM   Login
505             04/03/2015 10:12:59 PM   Login
505             04/03/2015 11:30:59 PM  logout
504             04/04/2015 3:31:41 PM   Login
504             04/04/2015 5:40:19 PM   logout
505             04/04/2015 5:43:40 PM   Login
505             04/04/2015 10:07:59 PM  logout
```

I expected this table:

```
Employee_id     date             login_time              logout_time
504             04/03/2015       04/03/2015 1:05:02 PM   04/03/2015 3:26:16 PM 
504             04/03/2015       04/03/2015 3:29:04 PM.  04/03/2015 3:30:25 PM
504             04/03/2015       04/03/2015 3:29:04 PM.  04/03/2015 3:30:25 PM
504             04/03/2015       04/03/2015 3:31:41 PM.  04/03/2015 5:40:19 PM
505             04/03/2015       04/03/2015 5:43:40 PM.  04/03/2015 8:17:59 PM
505             04/03/2015       04/03/2015 10:12:59 PM  04/03/2015 11:30:59 PM
```

I tried this code but it just kept the earliest time for login and latest time for logout:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Employee_id,
                CAST(time AS date) AS Date,
MIN(time) OVER (PARTITION BY Employee_id, CAST(time AS date) ORDER BY type) AS login_time,
MAX(time) OVER (PARTITION BY Employee_id, CAST(time AS date) ORDER BY type DESC) AS logout_time
from my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Form groups per logout by running a window function in *descending* order, counting logouts. Then pick the latest login from each group:

```sql
SELECT employee_id, ts::date
     , max(ts) FILTER (WHERE type = 'Login')  AS login_time
     , max(ts) FILTER (WHERE type = 'logout') AS logout_time
FROM  (
   SELECT *, count(*) FILTER (WHERE type = 'logout') OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id, ts::date ORDER BY ts DESC) AS grp
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
GROUP  BY employee_id, ts::date, grp
ORDER  BY employee_id, ts::date, login_time;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0rj0O10M)

I use the name "ts" for the `timestamp` column instead of the (misleading) basic type name "time".

Of course, this doesn't play well with sessions crossing the date boundary. But your question doesn't mention that possibility.